# trying to post form using RTK query to nodejs

Tags: node.js, rtk-query

trying to post to nodejs using RTK query mutation

```html
   **endpoint nodejs i have posted using 
fetch(`const handleAddproduct=()=>{ 
 fetch('http://localhost:9000/api/v1/admin/product/new',{
   method:"POST",
  headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
  body:JSON.stringify(newproduct)
}).then(()=>{
   console.log("new Product added")
 })
 }`*
but while using rtk mutation it's not post 
 const handleAddproduct=async()=>{
   await Addproductnew(createProduct).unwrap()
  .then((payload) => console.log('fulfilled', payload))
  .catch((error) => console.error('rejected', error))
}
  
 *export const productApi = createApi({
  tagTypes: ['Product'],
  reducerPath: 'productApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:9000/"  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProduct: builder.query({query:(id)=>createRequest(`api/v1/product/${id}`)}),
    getAllProductsByName: builder.query({query:()=>createRequest(`api/v1/products`)}),
    getOrderAdminByName: builder.query({query:()=>createRequest(`api/v1/admin/orders`)}),
    // AddOrdernew:builder.mutation({query:()=>createProductpost(`api/v1/order/new` )}),
    // Addproductnew:builder.mutation({query:()=>createProductpost(`api/v1/admin/product/new`)}),
    Addproductnew: builder.mutation({
            query: newproductid => ({
                url: 'api/v1/admin/product/new',
                method: 'POST',
                body: {newproductid}    
            }),
        }),
  }),
})***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
import from service mutation and createProduct in array wouldn't read it as a function    

const [createProduct]  =useCreateProductMutation();

form in homepage 
<form onSubmit={() => {createProduct(newProduct)}}>
{/* <form onSubmit={() => {createProduct(newProduct)}}> */}
<input type="text" value={title} placeholder="title" onChange={(e)=>settitle(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input  type="text" value={desc} placeholder="desc" onChange={(e)=>setdesc(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input type="text"  value={img} placeholder="img" onChange={(e)=>setimg(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input type="number" value={size} placeholder="size" onChange={(e)=>setsize(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input type="text"  value={color} placeholder="color" onChange={(e)=>setcolor(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input type="text"  value={category} placeholder="category" onChange={(e)=>setcategory(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input type="number" value={price} placeholder="price" onChange={(e)=>setprice(e.target.value)}/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>


service RTK query folder 
export const productApi = createApi({
//   tagTypes: ['Product'],
  reducerPath: 'productApi',
    tagTypes: ['Post'],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:9000/"  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProduct: builder.query({query:(id)=>createRequest(`api/v1/product/${id}`)}),
    getAllProductsByName: builder.query({query:()=>createRequest(`api/v1/products`)}),
    getOrderAdminByName: builder.query({query:()=>createRequest(`api/v1/admin/orders`)}),
    // AddOrdernew:builder.mutation({query:()=>createProductpost(`api/v1/order/new` )}),
    // Addproductnew:builder.mutation({query:()=>createProductpost(`api/v1/admin/product/new`)}),

   createProduct: builder.mutation({
   query: (newProduct) => {
    console.log("Create Product:", newProduct)
    return {
     url: `api/v1/admin/product/new`,
     method: 'POST',
     body: newProduct,
     headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     }
    }
   }
  }),
```